# Run multiple classes using Maven

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have a package with several classes (each one encapsulating an executable program, i.e. with a main() method), i.e.:

```
com.myorg.examples.classA
com.myorg.examples.classB
etc.
```

All the classes belong to the same package (`com.myorg.examples`).

I know I can use maven to run *one* of such classes, eg:

```
mvn exec:java -D"exec.mainClass"="com.myorg.examples.classA"
```

I also know I can configure exec-maven-plugin in order to do the same using a shorter command, eg:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>com.myorg.examples.classA</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

then use:

```
mvn exec:java
```

However, I wonder if it would be possible:

1. To use the exec-maven-plugin (or antoher one) to configure the several executions and do something like this

   ```
   mvn exec:classA       # or,
   mvn exec:java classA
   ```

   so classA is run, but using a shorter syntax than plain exec:java. Looking to the XML structure it seems only one class can be set, so I'm not sure how to achieve that.
2. <strike>To execute all the classes, in sequence, eg:</strike>

   ```
   mvn exec-all
   ```

   <strike>in order to run classA, next classB, and so on.</strike>

Any help or link about these topics will be highly welcomed. Thanks!

**EDIT:** second part of the question has been spined off to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51514614/aggregating-tasks-in-maven).

Comment: Part 1 of the question has been answered. Part 2 has been spined off to a different question, in order to make question-answers clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure several executions which is available since [Maven version 3.3.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html)

```
<project...>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.soebes.test.First</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>second-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.soebes.test.Second</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>third-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.soebes.test.Third</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins> 
  </build>
</project>
```

So you can now call Maven via:

The following will execute the one where id: `default-cli`:

```
mvn exec:java
```

The following will execute the one where id: `second-cli`:

```
mvn exec:java@second-cli
```

The following will execute the one where id: `thirds-cli`:

```
mvn exec:java@third-cli
```

The question is why you have several main classes in a different packages but within a single Maven module which sounds for me to have different modules (as you already have packages).. The other question is why do you need to execute them via exec-maven-plugin? What is the intention ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Actually, all the classes are in the same package (I have edited the question to make it clearer). With regards to exec-maven-plugin, I don't have special preference for that plugin... if the problem is solvable using some other, it alsa fine.

Comment: Why do you need to execute them via exec-maven-plugin? What is the purpose of that? Testing ?

Comment: Not sure of the bottom line of the question... I mean, as explained in my last comment, I'm not using exec-maven-plugin for any particular purpose. My goal is to be able to run separate classes (which happen to be part of the same Java package) using the "mvn" comman interface. If there is other mean to achieve that different from exec-maven-plugin but still using the "mvn" command, it is also fine.

Comment: Sorry but you didn't answer my question: Why do you need to execute your classes via exec-maven-plugin? What are you trying to achieve? If the answer is: no particular reason ? Than why are you trying to use it ? And asking about it?

Comment: I'm using exec-maven-plugin because I don't know any other alternative (using Maven) to do so :) As I told above, "if there is other mean to achieve that [executing Java classes] different from exec-maven-plugin but still using the "mvn" command, it is also fine".

Comment: Yes you told several times that you don't know any other alternative but for what ? What is what you like to achieve here ? Would you like to make an executable jar ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in pom.xml in relevant place

UTF-8
 
    
  com.springexamples.demo.MainClassOne
  com.springexamples.demo.MainClassTwo