# Aggregating tasks in Maven

Tags: java, maven

(Spin off from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51504549/run-multiple-classes-using-maven))

Maven allows to execute several tasks in the same command line, eg:

```
mvn exec:java@first-cli exec:java@second-cli exec:java@thrid-cli exec:java@fourth-cli exec:java@fifth-cli exec:java@sixth-cli exec:java@seventh-cli
```

However, this is a problem when you have a long list of commands to execute (as shown in the example above).

Is there any way using Maven to define an "aggregated task" (composed of several other tasks) in order to solve this situation?

Comment: just use pom.xml?

Comment: See my question on the original question...

Comment: What is the purpose of that? What are you trying to achieve here? Why would you like to do that? As I already asked: Testing ? A kind of integration tests?

Comment: The purpose is to be able to run a set of classes in sequence, one after other, using a short mvn command, using just one task after "mvn" instead of a task per class to be executed.